# При вводе команды - ошибка "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, json, requests, discord.py

Хотел подружить один API с Discord, но выдаёт ошибку, когда ввожу команду ">>profile {ник игрока}".
Ошибка:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\Desktop\VimeBot.py", line 16, in profile
    await ctx.send(f"""```Ник: {str(profile['username'])}
TypeError: string indices must be integers

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: string indices must be integers
````

Функция, которая отвечает за эту команду:

````
async def profile(ctx, arg1):
    profile = requests.get(f"https://api.vimeworld.ru/user/name/{arg1}").text
    jsonprofile = json.loads(profile)
    await ctx.send(f"""```Ник: {str(profile['username'])}
ID: {profile['id']}```""")
````

Comment: а что должно выдать "profile['username'])" если profile это обычная строка? Неужели вам непонятен текст ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

````
profile = requests.get(f"https://api.vimeworld.ru/user/name/{arg1}").text
jsonprofile = json.loads(profile)
await ctx.send(f"""```Ник: {str(profile['username'])}
````

Судя по вашему коду, у вас элементарная описка. Вам нужно было обращаться к `jsonprofile['username']`. Но ещё более правильно сразу получать `json` из `request`, а не парсить как `json` "вручную" текст ответа на запрос, судя по всему задумка была именно такая изначально. Кроме того, в ответе приходит *список* пользователей, по нему нужно итерироваться:

````
profile = requests.get(f"https://api.vimeworld.ru/user/name/{arg1}").json() # <-- изменено
for user in profile: # <-- добавлен цикл
    await ctx.send(f"""```Ник: {user['username']} # <-- изменено
````

Comment: Всё равно не работает. Выдаёт ошибку:
`Ignoring exception in command profile:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\Desktop\VimeBot.py", line 15, in profile
    await ctx.send(f"""```Ник: {str(profile['username'])}
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
`

Comment: @OniShlange Я проверил, по счастью я угадал с именем пользователя "123" и получил ответ. У вас там список в `json`, а внутри уже словарь. Я немного поменял ответ.

Comment: Теперь всё работает, спасибо!